# What adress does "&ref_var" points to?

Tags: c++, ref

Consider the following code:

```
std::vector &MyClass::getVector() const
{
    return (myVec);
}

void aFunc()
{
    std::vector *vec = &myClassInstance.getVector();
}
```

What adress does vec points to? Does it points to the very address of myVec in the myClassInstance object? (btw I know I should return a const ref, but it is an example).

Comment: why dont you try it out?

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a reference to `myVec` in the method `getVector`. When you take the address of a reference, you get the address of the variable the reference refers to. So `vec` will contain the address of `myVec`.

Comment: I wasn't sure about this behaviour. Thank you (as tobi303 suggested, i tried, and I confirm your answer )

Answer (score 2):

A reference is an alias to another variable.  When you return a reference to`myVec` from `getVector()` then you can consider calling the function to be exactly like accessing `myVec` if it were publicly available.

```
&MyClass.myVec == &myClassInstance.getVector()
```

> What adress does vec points to?

The address of `myClassInstance.getVector()` will be the same as the address of `myVec`.

Also note that since you are returning an lvalue reference you can even use it on the left hand side of an assignment like

```
myClassInstance.getVector() = some_other_vector;
```

And now `myVec` will be a copy of `some_other_vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does point to the very vector myVec in your MyClass instance. See the following sample code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

class MyClass {
    std::vector<int> myVec;

public:
    MyClass() {}
    ~MyClass() {}

    std::vector<int>& getVector()
    {
        return myVec;
    }

    void printVector() const
    {
        for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = myVec.begin(); it != myVec.end(); ++it)
        {
            printf("%d ", *it);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    MyClass item;

    std::vector<int>* vec = &(item.getVector());

    vec->push_back(1);
    item.printVector();

    return 0;
}
```

Running this program will output:

```
$ ./a.out 
1
```

So you can see that calling `getVector()` returns a reference to `myVec` from the MyClass instance, since we add a new item to the vector (`vec->push_back(1)`) via the `vec` pointer then print the MyClass instance's vector, and it shows that the item we added is there in `myVec`.